# Deployed .net application without app.config - Where is it getting its settings from and how to change them?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, app-config

I have a client with a deployed Winforms application. Due to a problem with the app's original developer, the client terminated their relationship with the developer. Some time later, the app's deficiencies go to a point where they needed to find another developer to help - which is when I came into the picture. One of the first things I discovered was that they did not have a copy of the source code! *(Edit: There were some 3 year old copies of the source code. They were too different to be usefult.)*

Despite not having any the source code, I've managed pretty well using a combination of dnSpy (a fork of ILSpy with an intergrated debugger and other additional features) and directly editting the data in the app's SQL server database (secured with intergrated security). However, the latest issue I've run up against is a perplexing one...

---

There is a screen where the display of records is limited to the year 2015. With the help of dnSpy, I found that this limit is retrieved from an app setting. Here's part one of the mystery : the application doesn't have an app.config in its deployed folder!

Doing some Google research, I found out about user.config files. I then discovered the user.config for the app file under `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\(CompanyName)\(AppName)(Hash)\1.0.0.0\`. I openned the config file and I found a setting with the same name that I was looking for and it had a value of '2015'. Eureka!... or so I thought.

I changed the setting in the user.config to '2016' but it didn't appear to affect the application when I ran it. I took a look at the user.config file again and the setting had been changed back to '2015'! So it looks like I have the correct user.config for the application because it is writing to the config file. Its just the app is reading its initial settings from somewhere else.

Some other things I've ruled out:

- I checked machine.config. Nothing there.
- In the decompiled MySettings file, I noticed DefaultSettingValue attributes on the setting property fields. Unfortunately, the setting that I'm looking at has a DefaultSettingValue of '2014'. So it doesn't appear to be using the default value for the setting.

---

So... TLDR;

Deployed .Net Winforms application. No matching appname.exe.config file in the same folder. Its not reading settings from a user.config file (though it is writing to the file).

Where could the application be reading its settings from?

Comment: You might be looking in the wrong place.  Look in `Users\USER NAME\AppData\LOCAL\(CompanyName)\(AppName)(Hash)\VERSION` (note the missing LOCAL).  That seems like it would more likely be an App setting

Comment: Actually, that was just a typo in my original post. The user.config path was under AppData\\Local. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: You could also use sysinternals' procmon to see which files the application access.

Comment: Yes, just because you see that value in Settings doesnt mean it is using it for that.  Even if you see code reading it, there could be *other code* getting it from elsewhere or calculating it

Answer (score 0):

As @Plutonix suggested, there could be other code getting at the setting and sure enough it was. Using Telerik JustDecompile to decompile and save the whole .exe into source files (Unfortunately, the generated solution would not compile in VS2015. So no quick solution for the no source code for the application problem), I searched through the text looking for other references to the setting.

I found it in the application's login form. During the form's load event it would read a value from the DB and assign it to the setting. After a successful login, that setting and various others would be saved (`MySettingsProperty.Settings.Save()`), thus updating the user.config. Why save this config setting when you are reading it from the DB only in the first place? Who knows...lol.

The other complication was due to the missing appname.exe.config file. Since the config file wasn't there, the application was using "default settings" - including for the connection strings. Turns out that the DB the application was reading the inital settings from was a dev DB. I solved this issue by using a copy of the .config file from a ClickOnce deployment I found in a subfolder of the application. (It was six months older that the deployed .exe file, but I crossed my fingers and gave it a try anyways). And... it worked!

---

In summary, there was no mysterious .Net config system mechanism going on there. Just the code reading the setting from a DB that I (initially) didn't have any control over.